# Set Up Port Listening And Forwarding

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I know, there are a lot of questions about opening ports and port forwarding. And I tried almost all of the answers but I cannot make it working for me.

I'm running a fresh installation of Kubuntu in a virtual machine.

I simply want to forward all traffic of [myip]:80 to localhost:8080. For testing purposes, I use netcat to listen on my ports.

So here is my complete set up (before these commands I deleted all iptable rules, including PRE/POSTROUTING):

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

To my understanding, now all connections will be accepted and forwarding is allowed (for all connections). Also, the prerouting will route all traffic on port 80 to localhost:8080.

Now I listen with:

```
sudo nc -l 10.0.2.15 80
sudo nc -l localhost 8080
```

I use the following commands on the same machine:

```
curl -XPUT http://10.0.2.15:80/
curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

In theory, my second listener should see both commands. In fact, the first listener will receive the first command and the second listener will receive the second one.
If I try from another machine the command **curl -XPUT http://10.0.2.15:80/** will result in a refused connection error. But I'm accepting *any* connections with the iptables configurations, don't I?

I did some experiments with POSTROUTING as well, but never succeeded. What am I missing? I tried for like 3h now... Thanks for any help.

//EDIT: I can successfully ping the virtual machine from another machine. And vice versa.

Comment: Learn more about netfilter!
1. PREROUTING is only change the destination ip on incoming traffic It doesn't handle the outbound traffic, which is want to go back with source ip 127.0.0.1.
2. PREROUTING chain is before routing, but when you connect to localhost there is no routing at all.

Read more papers, please!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know, that when I execute `curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:8080/` there will be no routing (because I connect to local host). Still, there is routing, when I connect from another machine! And even if the route is not set up correctly to get an answer back, I should still see something in netcat, shouldn't I? Instead, the whole connection is refused.

Comment: No. You've changed the packet to destination `127.0.0.1` _before_ routing. So the kernel got a packet in its routing process with 10.0.2.x --> 127.0.0.1, and because it's not listening for that ip on eth0 it will simply ignore it.

Comment: Ok, I got. Thanks! I found the solution, but I'd like to give you the credits because you pointed me into the right direction. So if you would post an (reasonable) answer I'll accept it as the correct one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Turned out, I was not that wrong but something was missing:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

Thanks to [Ipor Sircer](https://serverfault.com/users/368300/ipor-sircer) who pointed out, that the kernel will drop packets with 127.0.0.1 and thanks to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112232), that pointed out how to circumvent this restriction.

So, here again the full setup I'm using, if someone needs to do something similar (i.e. setting up port forwarding on a virtual machine to localhost):

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

Of course, change the ports and the interface to your settings. I.e. change **--dport** and **--to-destination** *AND* **eth0** in the second last and last command to your interface.

Also make sure every machine can really talk to each other - usually for a virtual machine you need to do some extra set up.